# How to STOP powershell rounding numbers off

Tags: powershell

I want to simply take 13.9 and X 1000 so i get 13900 but powershell seems to think i want 14000 - i cannot see how but how do i stop powershell rounding numbers!

Tried specifying [math]::Round and using 0 - 5 
i am sure its simple but i cannot find out how to do this.

$Script:Size1 = 13.9GB

```
            $Script:Size1 = $Script:Size1.Replace("GB", "")
            $Script:Size1.Trim()
            [System.Math]::Round([int]$Script:Size1 * 1000)
```

Tried changing the Zero to various Decimal places 0 - 5 everything i do it rounds to some extent but never NOT rounds

```
[Math]::Round([int]$Script:Size1 * 1000, 0)
```

Before Adding the Round i was still seeing it round - I tried adding teh round so i could specify the decimal place which might have helped but it did not.

Just to Clarify the $Script:Size1 = 13.9GB is just telling you what the Data is it is actually a string as it was read from a text file. Hence is take $Script:Size1 and * 1000 i get 1000 13.9's displayed as a huge String.

Sorry if that was misleading.

The issue is I have a String 13.9GB that i need to Strip the GB from and convert to an int so I can then * 1000 - that is the issue as soon as i convert to int it becomes 14 - i do not want that.

Comment: Please copy the text of the _actual_ code you are running and the output, then update your question with the results. (No screenshots, please.)

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `13.9*1000` returns `13900` as expected, so please add your code as instructed.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your `$Script:Size1` to an integer before doing your multiplication, and the `13.9` is thus being converted to an integer (rounded to `14`) before the operation is performed.

You should perform the multiplication first, ensuring that it is expressed as `$script:size1 * 1000` (this coerces the 1000 to a float), and then `[Math]::Round()` the result.

Note that assigning `$script:size1=13.9GB` is an actual number, not a string that you can remove "GB" from; you may want to rethink the problem.

Comment: trying this now - If i do 1000 * 13.9 as itsnot an integer it just gives me 1000 13.9's I need to declare as an int to do the math but its doing as you say turning 13.9 into 14 - how do i get round that? make 13.9 an int without rounding

Comment: Your code as given here can't possibly be what you are actually using; the indication is that your `13.9GB` is a string somehow - but _as given_, it isn't. How is `$script:size1` defined, and why are you using the `script:` scope indicator?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error that you're experiencing; if the variable is a string containing "13.9GB", when I multiply `1000 * $foo`, I get an integer `14925011353600`, just as though the 13.9GB was expressed as its numeric value. If, on the other hand, I multiply `$foo * 1000`, I get 1000 copies of the string `13.9GB` concatenated. ***Order of operands matters in PowerShell if they are not of the same type.***

Comment: What, ultimately, are you trying to do? Why are you trying to truncate the GB and then multiply by 1000?

Comment: So I am trying to turn 13.9GB into MB - I have alot of Data in a spreadsheet that is in TB / GB / MB / KB - i need to get differences between two values so I am converting everything to MB to do the difference calculation. if i do 1000 * $Script:Size1 ( without stripping the GB off so its 13.9GB ) I get this error Cannot convert value "13.9GB" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: if you are talking about the size of the disk, you can use this,  $size = (Get-Disk -Number 0 ).Size / 1GB;[math]::Round([int]$size) * 1000

Comment: I am not querying actual Drives this is Data from files

Comment: If your data is the string "13.9GB"  in the variable `$foo`, and you want it in MB, you want to use `[float]$foo / 1MB`. If you have any "bogus" characters in the string, you will get an error. But a number in GB is too big for an `[int]`.

Comment: Note also that using `KB`, `MB`, `GB`, does ***NOT*** use factors of 1000, but 1024 instead. These are "real" KB, MB, GB, not "sales" KB, MB, GB.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, despite that **`GB`** (Gigabyte) should actually be called **`GiB`** (Gibibyte), as **`KB`** ([Kilobyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte)) vs **`KiB`** ([Kibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte)).
For Microsoft Windows (PowerShell), and a lot of other hardware and software providers, **1KB = 1024 bytes** and **1GB = 1024<sup>3</sup>** bytes, see also: [KB: 1024 vs 1000](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/kb-1024-vs-1000/)

```
PS C:> 1KB
1024
PS C:\> 1GB
1073741824
PS C:\> 13.9GB, (1024 * 13.9MB), 14233.6MB, (13.9 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
14925011353.6
14925011353.6
14925011353.6
14925011353.6
```

As for what you are doing:

```
$Script:Size1.Trim()
```

Will just display `13` but not update `$Script:Size1`

`[Int]'13.9'` will make it a number but round `13.9` to an integer (whole number: `14`):

```
PS C:\> [Int]'13.9'
14
```

If you want the proper (automatic) type casting, you should simply put the numeric value first in the expression:

```
PS C:\> 1000 * '13.9'
13900

PS C:\> $Script:Size1 = '13.9GB'
PS C:\> 1000 * $Script:Size1.Replace('GB', '')
13900
```

But as stated at the beginning, this is actually correct:

> ```
> PS C:\> "13.9GB = $(1024 * $Script:Size1.Replace('GB', ''))MB"
> 13.9GB = 14233.6MB
> ```

Answer (score -2):

So I have found a way to do it by using [Float] and not [int]

[Float]$Script:Size1 * 1000

Gives a Value of 13899.9996185303 and that I am happy with I can then round that off or keep it as is for what i need to do.

[Float] was the key

Thanks for all your help though

Comment: This is the wrong thing to do - `[float]` is correct; see my comment to my answer - but ***1000*** is wrong - PowerShell uses 1KB = 1024, 1MB = 1024KB, 1GB = 1024MB, etc.